# How to find Graphql query datasource?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

Disclaimer: I am pretty new to this technology.

I have a website built with Gatsby that uses different data sources. Is there a way to understand if a specific graphql query on a page comes from a specific plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby sources it's data through underlying APIs that "Source Plugins" (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/creating-a-source-plugin/#what-is-a-source-plugin) use to populate Gatsby's data store. Those source plugins are most often npm packages that you can install, but you can also have a local source plugin in your `gatsby-node.js`. In the latter case you should read `gatsby-node.js` and see if it contains a `sourceNodes` export.

So you'll want to check your `gatsby-config.js` what `plugins` are defined there. This array can either directly contain the individual plugins or it can contain themes (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/themes/what-are-gatsby-themes/). Those themes itself will have a `gatsby-config.js` then.

So with this knowledge you know which source plugins are active in your site. They often namespace their queries, so e.g. `gatsby-source-contentful` has the namespace `allContentful`. You can explore those queries at `localhost:8000/___graphql` when you have `gatsby develop` running.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can distinguish the data source from the naming of the data types. if you go to `http://localhost:8000/___graphq`l while running the project in your local environment on the left side you can see all the data types. The data types usually starts with "all+data source" or just "data source name". In the picture below my data source is Contentful and all the data coming from there are starting with "allContentful+content name". [image]

Answer (score -1):

Inspect a page, Developer Tools => Network;
See every request that send your website;
what script send the request, is it yours or not ?
analyze the result of each request.
I think this can help.

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is created at build time, so there is no network call that I can inspect.